# List to struct conversion with automatical type field conversion

Tags: racket

I am reading .csv file and by

```
(define-struct my-struct (id name))
(apply my-struct '("5" "Tomas"))
(string? (my-struct-id (apply my-struct '("5" "Tomas"))))
```

converting it to struct. All fields are string however, is there some elegant way how to force `string->number` conversion on e.g. `id` field?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `(apply my-struct (map string->number '("5" "Tomas"))` ?

Comment: this breaks drracket... beside that i want only "5" to be converted to number and not "tomast" to #f

Comment: I was hoping for some more automatic way something like: `define-struct my-struct (id #:number name))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it there two options. The first one is the simplest, use a custom contructor:

```
; Option 1: Make a dedicated constructor that
;           handles the conversion.
(struct my-struct (id name) #:transparent)
(define (create-struct id name)
  (my-struct (string->number id) name))
```

The second option is to (ab)use a guard:

```
; Option 2: Use a guard
(define (converter id name the-struct-name)
  (values (string->number id) name))
(struct my-second-struct (id name) #:guard converter #:transparent)

(apply my-second-struct '("5" "Tomas"))
```

Comment: Related to option 1: when one wants to provide a struct with a modified constructor, one can do it like so:
`(provide (except-out (struct-out person) person) (rename-out [make-person person]))`

Answer (score 2):

To complete soegaard's answer, if you provide your struct and use it in other modules, you could also add a contract to prevent bad usage:

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/contract)
(provide (contract-out
          [struct person ((id number?) (name string?))]))

(struct person (id name))
```

```
> (require my-module/person)
> (person 42 "Margaret")
#<person>
> (person "haxxor" 1337)
; person: contract violation
;   expected: number?
;   given: "haxxor"
;   in: the 1st argument of
;       (-> number? string? person?)
```

See the full documentation here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-struct.html#(part._contracts-define-struct)

Comment: Thanks I will use contract as well, if I only could accept both answers.